# Html audio volume adjustment

Tags: html, audio, volume

I am trying to autoplay a background music to my website and start it playing at 10% volume. This is my code:

```
<audio id="bgAudio" autoplay src="music.mp3" volume="0.1"></audio>
```

This doesn't work for me. I've searched other ways on the internet but none of them worked. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Javascript to modify the volume after defining it because volume isn't a valid property for the audio tag. It SHOULD be IMO but it isn't. Try this:

```
<audio autoplay id="bgAudio">
  <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script>
  var audio = document.getElementById("bgAudio");
  audio.volume = 0.1;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Chrome) and check the Console tab, there should be some error messages. It seems that the problem is in wrong path to the .mp3 file.