# html5 audio volume does not change

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am trying to change the volume of some `HTML <audio>`. When I change the `volume` attribute, the playback volume seems to be exactly the same. See the following codePen for the described behaviour: https://codepen.io/christoffer-corfield-aakre/pen/rKjmeo

I expected the volume to change when I changed the volume attribute. Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Duplicate of [Html audio volume adjustment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141681/html-audio-volume-adjustment)